# Blank page occurs when editing item

Tags: php, mysql, twig

I am currently creating a car rental project where you can rent and return cars.
I have no issues with adding, editing and removing customers. Niether with renting and returning cars. However, when I want to edit and remove cars, they do indeed get deleted and updated in the database, but once I click on "remove car" or "edit car", it just goes to a blank page instead of generating the correct twig file. When I check the database, the car has been edited/removed.

The Cars table looks like this in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
    licensePlate VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    brand VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    colour VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    year VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    customerNumber CHAR(10),
    statusRented boolean not null default 0,
    start DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (licensePlate),
    FOREIGN KEY (colour) REFERENCES Colours(colour),
    FOREIGN KEY (brand) REFERENCES Brands(brand)
);
```

function in CarModel.php:

```
public function editCar($licensePlate, $newBrand, $newColour, $newYear, $newPrice)
  {
    $carsQuery = "UPDATE Cars SET brand = :brand, colour = :colour, year = :year, price = :price " .
      "WHERE licensePlate = :licensePlate";
    $carsStatement = $this->db->prepare($carsQuery);
    $carsParameters = [
      "licensePlate" => $licensePlate,
      "brand" => $newBrand,
      "colour" => $newColour,
      "year" => $newYear,
      "price" => $newPrice
    ];
    $carsResult = $carsStatement->execute($carsParameters);
    if ($carsResult) die($this->db->errorInfo()[2]);
  }
```

The functions in CarController.php:

```
public function editCar($licensePlate, $brand, $colour, $year, $price)
  {
    //$customerName = $map["customerName"];
    //$customerNumber = $map["customerNumber"]; 
    $CarModel = new CarModel($this->db);
    $fetchColours = $CarModel->fetchColours();
    $fetchBrands = $CarModel->fetchBrands();
    $properties = [
      "licensePlate" => $licensePlate,
      "oldBrand" => $brand,
      "oldColour" => $colour,
      "oldYear" => $year,
      "oldPrice" => $price,
      "colours" => $fetchColours,
      "brands" => $fetchBrands
    ];
    return $this->render("EditCar.twig", $properties);
  }

  public function carEdited($licensePlate, $oldBrand, $oldColour, $oldYear, $oldPrice)
  {
    $form = $this->request->getForm();
    $newBrand = $form["brand"];
    $newColour = $form["colour"];
    $newYear = $form["year"];
    $newPrice = $form["price"];
    $carModel = new CarModel($this->db);
    $carModel->editCar($licensePlate, $newBrand, $newColour, $newYear, $newPrice);
    $properties = [
      "licensePlate" => $licensePlate,
      "oldBrand" => $oldBrand,
      "newBrand" => $newBrand,
      "oldColour" => $oldColour,
      "newColour" => $newColour,
      "oldYear" => $oldYear,
      "newYear" => $newYear,
      "oldPrice" => $oldPrice,
      "newPrice" => $newPrice
    ];
    return $this->render("CarEdited.twig", $properties);
  }
```

The button in Twig(generated HTML):

```
<form method="post" action="/editCar/{{car.licensePlate}}/{{car.brand}}/{{car.colour}}/{{car.year}}/{{car.price}}">
              <input disabled type="submit" value="Edit">
            </form>
```

routes.json:

```
 "editCar/:licensePlate/:brand/:colour/:year/:price": {
    "controller": "Car",
    "method": "editCar",
    "params": {
      "licensePlate": "string",
      "brand": "string",
      "colour": "string",
      "year": "number",
      "price": "number"
    }
  },
  "carEdited/:licensePlate/:brand/:colour/:year/:price": {
    "controller": "Car",
    "method": "carEdited",
    "params": {
      "licensePlate": "string",
      "brand": "string",
      "colour": "string",
      "year": "number",
      "price": "number"
    }
  },
```

Only put up the information for the edit car function since I believe the remove car function most likely has the same issue. I was speculating that it was due to the columns start and rentedStatus not being mentioned, thus tried adding those to the parameters in different ways, but that unfortunately did not help. I have no such extra parameters in the Customers table.
How would one solve this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing `if ($carsResult) die($this->db->errorInfo()[2]);` in `editCar`, this will stop the script.

Comment: @DarkBee ohh thank you very much! I think I initially did that because I was hoping that it'd give me a helpful error message if things didn't work out, but clearly that wasn't the case :) I have now removed those lines from both removeCustomer and editCustomer and everything works perfectly fine now!
Thanks a bunch, wish you a lovely day!

Comment: No problem - note: You probably wanted to `if (!$carResult)` and print out the error